# how to make ubuntu install iso file for arm64 machine on x86-64 machine?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, chroot, debootstrap

I'm trying to install ubuntu 18.04 on a qemu virtual machine which is a modified version of qemu's arm `virt` machine.
I checked that I can install ubuntu 18.04 on arm `virt` machine as directed [here](https://futurewei-cloud.github.io/ARM-Datacenter/qemu/how-to-launch-aarch64-vm/), a very helpful page.
But when I try to install it on a modified machine, it fails, so I wanted to debug (follow) the ubuntu install procedures, if it's possible.
I thought I need to access the source code or scripts data for ubuntu install and found [this interesting page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) for making ubuntu .iso file.  (If I can compile some executable in debug mode and follow it, I might be able to see where the problem is.)
It tells me to use debootstrap command to extract all the bootstrap files to a directory. The command is below.

```
sudo debootstrap --arch=$ARCH $RELEASE chroot
```

I tried extracting for ubuntu 20.04 (focal fosa) because my ultimate goal is to install 20.04 on my virtual machine. So I tried `sudo deboostrap --arch=arm64 focal chroot` and it extracts the bootstrap data to directory `chroot`. The guide instructs me to install futher packages inside the chroot directory by entering bash with command `sudo chroot chroot`. But soon I found the `bash` executable inside the chroot directory is for arm64 when my host is amd64. I'm almost sure I need to do the job of installing ubuntu packages inside the chroot directory using an arm64 computer (whch I have one really) that can execute the bash and other arm64 binaries in the chroot file system. Is my understanding correct?  And this page looks very old (talking about versions from 2011 or 2012). Can anyone direct me to a more up-to-date information? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create ARM64 usable chroot you have to copy special QEMU static virtualization executable to it.

Use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install debootstrap binfmt-support qemu-user-static

sudo debootstrap --arch=arm64 focal chroot
sudo cp -av /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static chroot/usr/bin
sudo chroot chroot
```

and continue inside chroot.

---

Useful links to read:

- https://wiki.debian.org/Arm64Qemu
- https://linux-sunxi.org/Debootstrap
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RootfsFromScratch/QemuDebootstrap

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you! I'll read your links.