# Why I was not able to get any system updates (via both software Updater & APT) after adding foreign architecture?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, architecture

After adding a new foreign architecture to Ubuntu 21.04 I was no longer able to get any updates using niether automatic software updater, nor `apt update`.

The only workaround I found was removing the added foreign architecture (in this case armhf) by issuing `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf`.

Right after removing it, I got the accumulated updates since the foreign architecture was added till after removing it (without rebooting the system).

I would like to know the resoan(s) of the issue. (Was it a bug? anyone else facing it?)

Thanks for your time and effort answering my question in advanced.

**Edit 1:**

Output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` was:

```
i386 armhf
```

Output of `dpkg --print-architecture` is:

```
amd64
```

The problem was on ASUS N551JW laptop.

Comment: Please add the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and `dpkg --print-architecture` to the question. What kind of hardware do you use?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The info is added to the original post. @N0rbert

Answer (score 1):

Two moments about *armhf* CPU architecture - it needs virtualization, its packages are located in different mirror server.

So when you run the following commands on fresh *amd64* system:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

you will get the following errors on next run of `sudo apt-get update`:

> ```
> E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute/multiverse/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.3.222 8000]
> E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.3.222 8000]
> E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute-security/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.3.222 8000]
> E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hirsute-backports/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 192.168.3.222 8000]
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
> ```

so APT will become seriously broken.

So you have remove *armhf* foreign architecture from the system by `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf` and then run `sudo apt-get update` again to keep things in order.

From my understanding there is only one correct foreign architecture for *amd64* - it is 32-bit variant named *i386*. Many packages are using it, for example Wine.

Comment: I got exactly same errors as you displayed it. Is there any other procedure/instruction I need to follow in order to get it running on my system? (I mean having the armhf alongside..) As you mentioned virtualisation, I had also installed QEMU. How to make the addition of armhf architecture work without corruption of APT?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346397/66509), but replace `arm64` with `armhf` ; and `/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static` with `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static`.

Comment: The provided answer link (with suggested subtitution) doesn't help. I am getting the same error as you illustrated above. Although, I added the armhf architecture before running your suggested codes in the povided link.